# How to add a link to a navigation drawer item?

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer

I'm trying to add a simple link to a Rate Theme item in the navigation drawer so when clicked users are brought to the Play Store listing of the application. I want to add it as a main navigation drawer item, right below Icon Request. How do I accomplish this?

https://www.dropbox.com/s/5dufwie8ejgygg2/2015-08-01%2010.28.50.png?dl=0

```
/*******************************************************************
 ************************* Drawer Clicks ***************************
 *******************************************************************/

private void setNavigationListener(NavigationView view){
    view.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
            closeDrawer();
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.navigation_home:
                    menuItem.setChecked(true);
                    addFragment(new HomeFrag(), HomeFrag.FRAG_TAG, false, 0, getString(R.string.drawer_home));
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_apply:
                    menuItem.setChecked(true);
                    addFragment(new LauncherFrag(), LauncherFrag.FRAG_TAG, true, 1, getString(R.string.drawer_launcher));
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_wallpaper:
                    if (!NetworkUtil.getNetworkState(activity)) {
                        dialogConnection();
                    } else {
                        if (UtilCat.getValue() == null) {
                            addFragment(new RetryFrag(), RetryFrag.FRAG_TAG, false, 99, getString(R.string.retry));
                        } else {
                            menuItem.setChecked(true);
                            final Fragment walls = new WallpaperFrag();
                            final Bundle args = new Bundle();
                            mDataCat = UtilCat.getValue();
                            node = mDataCat.get(0);
                            args.putSerializable(WallpaperFrag.BUNDLE_TAG, node.wallpaperList);
                            walls.setArguments(args);
                            addFragment(walls, WallpaperFrag.FRAG_TAG, true, 2, getString(R.string.drawer_wallpaper));
                        }
                    }
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_icons:
                    menuItem.setChecked(true);
                    addFragment(new IconsFrag(), IconsFrag.FRAG_TAG, true, 3, getString(R.string.drawer_icons));
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_request:
                    menuItem.setChecked(true);
                    addFragment(new IconRequestFrag(), IconRequestFrag.FRAG_TAG, true, 4, getString(R.string.drawer_request));
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_sub_contact:
                    addFragment(new ContactFrag(), ContactFrag.FRAG_TAG, false, 99, getString(R.string.drawer_contact));
                    return true;


                case R.id.navigation_sub_changelog:
                    mCurrentSelectedPosition = 99;
                    AsyncTaskIconsNew aTask;
                    MaterialDialog dialog = new MaterialDialog.Builder(activity)
                            .title(R.string.changelog)
                            .customView(R.layout.dialog_changelog, false)
                            .positiveText(getResources().getString(R.string.close))
                            .theme(getDialogTheme())
                            .build();
                    WebView webView = (WebView) dialog.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.webview);
                    webView.getSettings();
                    int theme = ApplyTheme.getConfigTheme(activity);
                    webView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.transparent));
                    if (theme == 0){
                        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/changelog_light.html");
                    } else {
                        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/changelog_dark.html");
                    }
                    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                            if (url != null) {
                                view.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
                                return true;
                            } else {
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    GridView gridView;
                    gridView=(GridView) dialog.getCustomView().findViewById(R.id.icon_grid);
                    gridView.setNumColumns(getResources().getInteger(R.integer.column_count_icon_dialog));
                    gridView.setStretchMode(GridView.STRETCH_COLUMN_WIDTH);
                    aTask = new AsyncTaskIconsNew(gridView, dialog);
                    aTask.updateActivity(activity);
                    aTask.execute();
                    dialog.show();
                    return true;

                default:
                    return false;
            }
        }
    });
}

/************************ Setup UI *************************/
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    AnalyticsTrackers.getInstance().get(AnalyticsTrackers.Target.APP).setScreenName(TAG);
    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    mActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    if (mActionBar != null) {
        mActionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.app_ic_drawer_menu);
        mActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

    setupPreLollipopStatusBar();
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mNavigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
    setNavigationListener(mNavigationView);

    mProgress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.base_progressSpinner);

    mFabHome = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab_home);
    mFabRequest = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab_request);
    mFabContact = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab_contact);
    mCoordinator = (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_content);
    mAppbar = (AppBarLayout) findViewById(R.id.appbar);

    mToolbarCollapse = false;

    activity = this;

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        initializeData();
    } else {
        //Not null repoduce last wallpaper state
        //Get data for Wallpaper and Icons fragments to save state on rotation
        node = (NodeCategory) savedInstanceState.get(KEY_LIST_DATA);
        mCurrentSelectedPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION);
    }

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    int licensed = intent.getIntExtra("LICENSED",0);
    if (licensed == 1)
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, getString(R.string.licensed), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: You have provided listener code, please provide code where you are inflating your navigation drawer or custom list adapter if you have implemented it in this way. Or you want to just add another listener ? Just add case statement with your item id

Comment: I'm just confused on what format to use for the rate theme listener that will go below navigation_request id. If I used the same structure as those, would I need to create a new fragment that includes the weblink?

Comment: You need to add it your view (layout) Another item under the Icon Request ? So provide code where are you adding(inflating) other navigation drawer items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.
.
.
case R.id.rateApp:
                AppRater app = new AppRater();
                app.rateNow(YourActivity.this);
                return true;
```

Create the following classes:

AppRater class:

```
public class AppRater{

private static Market market = new GoogleMarket();

public static void rateNow(final Context context) {
        try {
            context.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, market.getMarketURI(context)));
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException activityNotFoundException1) {
            Log.e(AppRater.class.getSimpleName(), "Market Intent not found");
        }
    }
```

GoogleMarket class

```
public class GoogleMarket implements Market {
    private static String marketLink = "market://details?id=";

    @Override
    public Uri getMarketURI(Context context) {
        return Uri.parse(marketLink + context.getPackageName().toString());
    }
}
```

Market class:

```
public interface Market {
    public Uri getMarketURI(Context context);
}
```

If your application is published on google play, it will get your app's id automatically and open the app on play store.